# jquery like code not working inside switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

My code is

```
//global variable
var topMenuSelected = 'Hot';

function switchMenu() {
     switch(topMenuSelected){
            case 'Hot':
                ${'#hotMenu'}.css('color', '#fff');
                break;
            case 'All':
                ${'#allMenu'}.css('color', '#fff');
                break;
        default:
                break;
        }
}
```

Here hotMenu and allMenu are ids of a tag `<a>`. On click of these links I am calling this function to change the color of `<a>`. But the error like invalid character is coming for `$` character in switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to use "(" rather than "{"

```
${'#hotMenu'}.css('color', '#fff');

$('#hotMenu').css('color', '#fff');
```

Answer (score 4):

A few things

First change `${'#hotMenu'}` to `$('#hotMenu')`

Also make sure you are loading jQuery first, and its also a good idea to wrap your intiliazing code within

```
$(function(){
    //Code here
});
```